# AMSupportURL* “is implemented in both”?

Tags: macos, iterm

[I read this thread and do not really understand the reply](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407603). I am getting the same error the first time I run iTerm2 after a reboot on a mac M1.

The author of that reply said

> It means two symbols are defined twice in the git program that’s first
> in your path (or that you call by a full path).

Is this a bug in iTerm2?

Comment: This error isn’t a problem. Do you have issues other than seeing that message logged?

Comment: no, it just bugs me.

Comment: Fair enough  - that’s reasonable